# how to add up values out of a list with a dictionary inside a list with python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I already tried to do it myself but I get 1 back and I dont know why. I thought i will be 5.

the code:

```
test_list = []

for i in range(5):
    test_list.append({"number": 1, "name": "Smith"})


for i in range(len(test_list)):
    number_list = []
    number_list.append(test_list[i]["number"]) 


x = sum(number_list)
print(x)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I suggest adding `print()` statements to debug your code. For example, does `print(number_list)` show what you expect?

Comment: i already did the print troubleshoot, why gives x a value of 1 instead of 5? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Just printing the end result isn't troubleshooting. You need to observe the intermediate values while the program is running.

Comment: Think about this: how many times do you want to create a new list to contain the resulting numbers, and how many times does the code actually do it?

Comment: i already did that, i just did not typed it here....

Comment: @mkrieger1, ohhhh thats why, everytime it loped i create a new list and that is why it only lists the last value, thank you!

Comment: @TomasO Your suggested changes might give the result of `5` but doesn't address underlying issue in the second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you guys i made it work, the fault was that everytime it loped it made `number_list = []` again. so in this new code it only makes `number_list = []` when i is 0, so only for the first time it loops.

```
test_list = []

for i in range(5):
    test_list.append({"number": 1, "name": "Smith"})

for i in range(len(test_list)):
    if i == 0:
        number_list = []
    number_list.append(test_list[i]["number"])


x = sum(number_list)
print(x)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can put `number_list = []` before the for loop. Then you don't need an `if`.